# No me funcionan las restricciones por clave ajena en mysql

Tags: mysql

Tengo el siguiente inconveniente con mysql:
he creado una base de datos en la que están conectadas varias tablas mediante sus respectivas llaves foráneas; tengo una tabla administrador que contiene los campos id_admin, nombre,...., y otra tabla libro con id_li,fecha_inicio_li, fecha_fin_li y la fK administrador_id-administrador pero cuando ingreso el registro de un nuevo libro con un administrador que no existe, este se crea normalmente, y no deberia pasar; esto me pasa en todas mis tablas que tiene referencias de FK. Así cree la tabla

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `HistoriasLaborales`.`libro` (
  `idlibro` INT NOT NULL,
  `fecha_inicio` DATE NOT NULL,
  `fecha_fin` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `administrador_id_administrador` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idlibro`),
  INDEX `fk_libro_administrador1_idx` (`administrador_id_administrador` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_libro_administrador1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`administrador_id_administrador`)
    REFERENCES `HistoriasLaborales`.`administrador` (`id_administrador`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

¿Cómo lo arreglo? ¿Qué debo hacer?

Comment: podrias facilitar los datos de la tabla administrador en un query, para que pueda replicar lo mismo.

Comment: A mí la restricción me funciona perfectamente, si intento registrar un administrador inexistente no me deja insertar el registro. Tal vez el error esté en otro punto. ¿Tal vez tengas `SET @@foreign_key_checks=0;`?